# Is there a way to add properties containing lists via Gremlin in Cosmos DB?

Tags: azure, gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I am looking to add a list property to an edge via gremlin in Cosmos DB. Currently, I it seems to only work with vertices,

```
g.addVertex('V1').property(list,'plist',1).property(list,'plist',2)
```

This works great, but

```
g.V().has('name','VertexName').as('a').V().has('name','VertexName2').addE('edge').from('a')
.property(list, 'metainfo', 'urls', {urls})
.property(list, 'metainfo', 'dates', "some date")
.property(list, 'metainfo', 'a', 1).property(list, 'metainfo', 'b', 2)
```

doesn't

Answer (score 0):

The ApacheTinkerPop project currently defines Gremlin such that list and set cardinality properties are only allowed on vertices and not on edges.